# Asp.NET GridView not showing data after binding with data table

Tags: asp.net

Can any one tell me why this code is not working?
I am trying to bind the DataTable(array of data table) with a grid view control but the grid view do not show any data and there is no error shown when running the code.

```
void GetTop()
        {
            int DtIndex = Convert.ToInt32(TxtNoGroups.Text);
            String cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            DataTable[] Groups = new DataTable[DtIndex];
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 4 * from student ORDER BY GRADE DESC", con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DtTopStudents = new DataTable();
                DtTopStudents.Load(rdr);
                for (int i = 0; i < DtTopStudents.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    Groups[i] = new DataTable();
                    Groups[i].TableName = "Group" + i;
                    Groups[i].Columns.Add("ID");
                    Groups[i].Columns.Add("Name");
                    Groups[i].Columns.Add("Grade");
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < DtIndex; i++)
                {
                    dr = Groups[i].NewRow();
                    dr = DtTopStudents.Rows[i];
                    Groups[i].ImportRow(dr);
                }
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = Groups[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Please don't post your code [as an image](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332), but instead copy/paste any relevant code and use [code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). If others want to test your code we have to type it in all over again.

Comment: Did you make sure `Groups[0]` contains data?

Answer (score 0):

debug and check if Groups[0] has data or is it null , if it has no data go back 1 step and control DtTopStudents ...

Comment: I checked it and Only `Group[0]` has no Row. Please can I any one tell why is this happening?